# How to sort all child Panels using title in alphabetical order in ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

I have list of child panels in a container where I am adding dynamically using an object.

```
var childObjects = [
                      {
                        title: 'xyz',
                        tagName:'overview'
                      },
                       {
                        title: 'eabc',
                        tagName:'overview'
                      },
                        {
                        title: 'aedf',
                        tagName:'overview'
                      }
                   ];
```

The above object is coming from backend call,using this object I am creating panel objects and adding it to my container like below.

```
                var array = [];
               for(var i=0;i<childObject.length;i++){
                   array.push({
                                    xtype:'panel',
                                    title: childObject[i].title
                              });
               }
             Ext.suspendLayouts();
              container.add(array);
            Ext.resumeLayouts();
```

my childObjects is not coming in alphabetic order from backend call. I want to make all child panels display in alphabetic order using title property. Please help me.

Comment: @Dalorzo How is that relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort the objects in the array:

```
childObjects.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.title;
    b = b.title;

    if (a === b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
});
```